# Compiling issue (on tissot_sprout)

Tags: android, gcc, kernel

I decided to compile stock kernel with upstreamed Linux patches for Mi A1 (tissot_sprout) so I used the source from http://github.com/android-linux-stable/tissot and the branch tissot-o-oss-8.1 (for 8.1) and when the compile process is going, I get this:

```
net/ipv4/fib_semantics.o
drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/isp/msm_isp_util.o
In file included from drivers/media/platform/msm/camera v2/isp/msm isp util.c:24:03
include/trace/events/msm cam.h:19:21: fatal error: msm isp.h: No such file or directory
   #include "msm_isp.h"
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target 'drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/isp/msm_isp_ut
il.o' failed
make[6] [drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/isp/msm_isp_util.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'drivers/media/platform/
msm/camera_v2/isp' failed
make[5]: [drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/isp] Error 2

scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2' failed
make[4]: [drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target "drivers/media/platform/msm' failed
make [3]: [drivers/media/platform/msm] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'drivers/media/platform'  failed

make[2]: [drivers/media/platform) Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'drivers/media' failed
make[1]: [drivers/media] Error 2
Makefile: 965: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: [drivers] Error 2
make: Waiting for unfinished jobs....
net/ipv4/fib_trie.o
net/ipv4/inet_fragment.o
```

Is there any fix for that?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect build log messages in **textual form**, not as images. Please, [edit] the question and past build log as a text. You may format it as a code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Done with that.